# Editable PDF on iPad?

Tags: pdf, ipad

I don't know if I am in the right section so I sincerely apologise if I am somewhere lost right now.

I have an Etsy store selling Printable designs. Either they buy it and I print it for them, or they can download specific files to print on their own. One of those designs is a planner and somebody wrote to me today asking if they can use it on their iPad?!

Now I have seen on Etsy something in that region. What some stores do is create an editable PDF file, for example for wedding suites, where the buyer can simply change the names and other text information to your preference without having to ask the seller/designer to edit the information for them.

However, is there something like that for an iPad?

Comment: Have you checked the app store?

Comment: @BillyKerr What exactly am I looking for? That is the thing, I am not really sure what it is I have to work to make or create? :/

Comment: You could try searching for "PDF editor" to begin with. Perhaps look at online reviews of similar apps.

Comment: Would a non-PDF approach work? For example, you could make e.g. Powerpoint files available for download by those who have a copy of PowerPoint or supply a link to the online version so that pretty much anyone with a browser could edit the files.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg That does sound like a good idea. The person just messaged me, "Can I use this for my iPad?" and I didn't know how to answer. The app sounds like a good direction too but that is far from my field. So I might have to pass on this person. However I was wondering if maybe there was a simplier version. Something like Google Keep but um I guess... through a PDF?! Or non... Ahhh!!!

Comment: Have a look here:  https://office.live.com/start/PowerPoint.aspx  you need an MS account but it's free.  And MS keeps making the web version of PPT more feature-rich all the time.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thank you! I will check that out and see if it fits into what I need for this person. I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily edit PDFs on an iPad in Liquid Text, in BlueBeam Revu, in Acrobat, PDF Expert Editor, or even graphic design tools like Affinity Designer for iPad... and there are a bevy of other options out there too - these all just happen to be on *my* iPad Pro so I *know* they work for this purpose - so your potential end-users have in fact a ton of options.

For what it's worth - they have even more options for PDF mark-up, including things like Morpholio trace, Concepts App and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice! I am not an apple user nor do I own an iPad at the current moment, so please excuse the lack of knowledge. However, are the softwares/apps that you mentioned something for this person to use and edit my work on their own, or something I have to prepare to give them to use in an edited form? I just need to figure out how I need to proceed. Whether I am to give her advice as to where to use it, or say please be patient I am creating an editable form for you.

Comment: With Liquid Text or PDF Expert Editor, or with Affinity Designer, you'd leave the relevant text entry spot blank, and they'd add in their text on their iPad - with Acrobat, you could create a PDF form and that would work well. Liquid Text also supports PDF forms.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and patience with my questions, @GerardFalla! I will look into the names you have provided and try to make something that this customer can use!